# Adding Phonegap files to android kernel except html css and jquery files

Tags: android, cordova, kernel, native

I am basically a Web Developer. I used the Phonegap tool to build Android iOS and RIM apps. I want to include the Corodova.jar file and Phonegap.js file inside Android Kernel(inside Android OS).So Every time i dont want to add these two files inside my android APP.I want to have these files to be stored in android kernel and be execute when any phonegap project runs so as the increase speed of excecution similar to the native app

Existing Phone Gap Model :
Inside Every app contains the corodova.jar files and phone gap .js file occur
And the app is executed

My idea - by "Maxymus Boopathy"(type it in google and search , You will find me

Inside Android OS/ kernel
Keeping /storing Corodova.jar and JS file and all
Files except the html and CSS
So that every time during execution the app will take the 
Corodova.jar and js files from android kernel and use it for all phonegap apps
Benefits : Low file Size , high performance increase the speed of the app

By  “Maxymus Boopathy” (type it google and fined me)
I have the Only name in the world no other is having tis name expect me!!!

Comment: Why?I think it may be possible. If we encourage the smartphone developers to include these files inside thier core, then Phonegap application will behave as an native app.Performance of the APP will also be greatly enhanced.It wil bring a revolution in smartphone usage.It will completely devast the usage of various platforms

Comment: The reason PhoneGap exists is because the device vendors are lagging behind implementing HTML5 API's. Eventually those API's will be implemented by the vendors but in the meantime use PhoneGap.

Comment: whether it is worth of doing?or not possible

Comment: The only folks who can include this functionality in the Android WebView, which is what I believe you mean by Android kernel, is Google. They will be slow to adopt. Until then that's why we work our tail off on PhoneGap.